# I'm having trouble writing an encryption code

Tags: python, encryption

Edit: Looks like I used the wrong operator for module. The program works great now. Thanks everyone.

In my Intro to Computing class, I have to write a code that encrypts and decrypts messages. #The program uses two encryption methods of encryption. One uses a method similar to ROT 13, and the other one puts the message in reverse order. The method similar to ROT 13 uses a key 31, because I'm using 62 characters. It should be a twoway encryption, but it's not functioning correctly. It's missing the correct encryption by one. For example, 'A' should change to 'f', but it changes to 'e'. Also, I'm get this error that says

"Please enter a message: Hello fellow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 16, in 
IndexError: string index out of range"

whenever I input 'f'. Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks, and here's the code.

```
characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'


message = input('Please enter a message:')

newmessage = ''


key = (31)
for symbol in message:

  if symbol.isalnum():
    position = characters.find(symbol)
    newposition = (position + key) & len(characters)
    newcharacters = characters[newposition]
    newmessage = newmessage + newcharacters
  else:
    newmessage = newmessage + symbol




finalmessage = newmessage

print('Your new message is ' + (finalmessage[::-1]))
```

Comment: what is the `&` supposed to do? I think if you change it to `%` you should be set

Comment: I think you meant to use modulo operator (%) here: `newposition = (position + key) & len(characters)`

Comment: As for the issue with the wrong index, I'd just change `(position + key)` to `(position + key + 1)`. If it's stupid but it works :/